# Why doesn't i<Ctrl-R>=expandcmd('se shm') work?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to do `i<Ctrl-R>=expandcmd('se shm')` and more generally `i<Ctrl-R>=expandcmd({expr})` but I'm just getting the literal {expr} inserted.

When I type `:se shm<CR>` I get the value of the option printed on the command-line. I'd like that inserted into my buffer.

Comment: It might help to explain what you're trying to achieve in the first place by using `expandcmd(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expandcmd()` expands wildcards, environment variables and such. It is not intended for VimScript execution.

In general, you can use `execute()` function to run VimScript interpreter and get the ouput as a string. But in this case it's enough to use &-notation (see `:h expr-option`):

```
i<C-R>=&shm
```